# PHP equivalent of "openssl cms -in input.txt -out encrypted.p7m -encrypt cert.pem"

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I am trying to find the PHP equivalent of "openssl cms -in input.txt -out encrypted.p7m -encrypt cert.pem".   I have an input file and a certificate.  Using the openssl command I can encrypt a text file using this method.  I am using S/MIME but not for the purposes of email, so I don't want to deal with email recipients or subjects, etc.

I tried openssl_pkcs7_encrypt() but it doesn't seem to be outputting the same bits.  Would openssl_encrypt() work?  I can't figure out how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to put it out there, is this something you could achieve using an `exec()` call?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  I don't want to use an exec() call because that will limit the systems that I can run this on.  Using exec() would work fine on my local machine but not my web host which doesn't allow binaries to run, such as openssl.

Comment: Ah fair enough. Just thought I'd put it out there in case you hadn't considered it :)

Comment: Hi, have you solved this?

Comment: Never solved this.  I'm not using this code much anymore but I ended up using exec() so the code couldn't run in the environment that I was planning.